# Get a Data from CSV from submited form using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, octobercms, laravel-excel

I am currently developing in OctoberCMS which uses Laravel and a built in AJAX framework.

Upon submission of a form, I am trying to capture data in a CSV and ultimately load it into the database. I am using [Laravel Excel v1.2.2](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) And the code i have written will only work if the CSV is loaded to the server as i am referencing a URL. I need this to instead load a CSV that is captured from a form. Here is my code:

```
Excel::load('my/url.xlsx' function($archive)
{
    $result = $archive->get();

    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value-> //Echoing some values here
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: can i see October cms code file upload and all this ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue trying to upload to an API endpoint using Laravel-Excel. For my needs, I compromised and uploaded to a temp directory and immediately read from there. Your example might look something like this:

```
if (Input::hasFile('file_from_form')) {
    Input::file('file_from_form')->move('uploads/my', 'url.xls'); // Moves to /public/uploads/my/url.xls
}

Excel::load('uploads/my/url.xls' ,function($archive)
{
    $result = $archive->get();

    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value-> //Echoing some values here
    }
})->get();
```

You can delete the temp files after you're done if desired. I wouldn't put this all in one place but did this just for simpler demonstration. For me, I checked and captured input from the controller then passed to a handler class to read and deal with the files data.

See the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files) for different methods available to uploaded files.